# different behaviors for zxing decode on Android and IOS

Tags: android, iphone, decode, qr-code, zxing

I've finished encoding text to QR code on Android, and the decoding part works well too. And just for fun, I encode Chinese words to QR code, zxing on Android can recognize it well. However, I tried zxing iPhone app, it fails decoding Chinese (no result after long time, while it only takes 1 second for Android code to return the recognized text). I didn't look at the zxing sdk for IOS yet, just curious why the apps from the same company will behave different on those two platforms, I assume the algorithm should be the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing isn't a company, it's an open source project.

More to the point, in this case, the people that work on the Java (Android) and C++ (iOS) ports overlap but aren't the same. And as mentioned in the ZXing FAQ, the ports are not equivalent.

However, the QR code suport in Java and C++ are pretty carefully kept in sync, so the results shouldn't be much different. Your best bet would be to post the code that's causing problems to the ZXing mailing list so folks have the chance to investigate.

(FWIW, I'm one of the most frequent contributors the C++/iOS ZXing port.)

Comment: Is it possible to scan a qr code from a screenshot I took on my android phone using zxing?

Answer (score 4):

As you are not Chinese, but you found this problem.You must be a good tester. As you know, zxing decode is difference from iOS and Android. It can be said zixng iOS is subset of zxing Android(I think). If you want to support Chinese  in zxing iOS, You have to improve the StringUtils.cpp in c++ port. Add these codes may help you.

```
if (length > 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        int value = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        if (value > 0x7F) {
            if (value > 0xB0 && value <= 0xF7) {
                int value2 = bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                if (value2 > 0xA0 && value2 <= 0xF7)
                    return GB2312;
            }
        }
    }
}
```